# awk capitalize manipulation and conditional if matching

Tags: bash, awk, capitalization

I am trying to manipulate a text stream where the second column needs to be lower case along with the fourth..(this works) However, in my case, the fifth may have a word or words.. in that case, I want to capitalize the first letter and lower case the rest of the word (or words)

```
cat payload/consolidated.csv | awk -F'","|^"|"$' '{print tolower($2),"~",tolower($4),"~",toupper(substr($5,1,1)) tolower(substr($5,2))}'
```

but this is failing to capitalize subsequent words.. it works only for the first word in that fifth column match

ideas?

Likewise and as a follow-on, how would I put a conditional if for that fifth column such that if it matched USA (example), that I would keep it USA. and not be Usa

Appreciated.

---

Sample Data input

```
"IGNORE","Why","IGNORE","Where","FirstName LastName Country"
```

Desired output

```
why~where~Firstname Lastname Country
```

(and then I want to be able to conditionally modify Country such that if it is actually USA, then I ignore the tolower()  )

Comment: Post some sample data with the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Command looks ok to me at first glance. Could you please post samples once?

Comment: just added some sample data

Comment: See https://ideone.com/TtfYDh, it works if you shift the columns.

Comment: Add a sample with the USA and conditional lowering also, please.

Comment: You said `the fifth may have a word or words.. in that case,` and showed us **that** case, now update your sample input and expected output to include the **other** case too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"       # using FPAT to separate fields
    OFS="~"                             # output field separator
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                  # remove quotes from fields
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)         
    b=""                                # buffer the case play
    while(match($5,/ *[A-Za-z]+ */)) {  # collect the "words" and upper first char, lower rest
        b=b toupper(substr($5,RSTART,1)) tolower(substr($5,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)) # sorry 2Pac...
        $5=substr($5,RSTART+RLENGTH)    
    }
    print tolower($2),tolower($4),b
}' file
```

Output:

```
why~where~Firstname Lastname Country
```

Waiting for that conditional casing example.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have `FPAT` in my system so going with usual  `FS` field separator setting here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="[ |,|\"]"
  s1=" "
  OFS="~"
}
{
  print tolower($5),tolower($11),\
        toupper(substr($14,1,1)) \
        tolower(substr($14,2)) s1 \
        toupper(substr($15,1,1)) \
        tolower(substr($15,2)) s1 \
        toupper(substr($16,1,1)) \
        tolower(substr($16,2))
}'  Input_file
```

In case of you want to know field number and their respective field values for lines then you could run following command it will be eaiser to understand above more.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ |,|\"]";OFS="~"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i,$i}}'  Input_file
```